# check cookie on page load in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I want to check cookie on page load in react. After the page load the function `checkCookie` not executed because the `console.log` inside the function not appear in console. how to execute the `checkCookie`? Here my code :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
function App() {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["janganTampil"]);
  const [isCookieSet, setIsCookieSet] = useState(false);
  // state for modal
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  function checkCookie() {
    const tampil = cookies.janganTampil === 'true';
    if (tampil) {
      setIsCookieSet(true);
    } else {
      handleShow();
    }
    console.log(isCookieSet);
    console.log(show);
  }
  return (
    <div onLoaded={checkCookie} className="App">
      ...
      {/* Tutorial is modal */}
      <Tutorial isCookieSet={isCookieSet} setIsCookieSet={setIsCookieSet} cookies={cookies} setCookie={setCookie} removeCookie={removeCookie} handleClose={handleClose} show={show} ></Tutorial>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the Effect Hook (useEffect)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

function App() {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["janganTampil"]);
  const [isCookieSet, setIsCookieSet] = useState(false);
  // state for modal
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  function checkCookie() {
    const tampil = cookies.janganTampil === 'true';
    if (tampil) {
      setIsCookieSet(true);
    } else {
      handleShow();
    }
    console.log(isCookieSet);
    console.log(show);
  }

  // Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    checkCookie();
    console.log('useEffect called');
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      {/* Tutorial is modal */}
      <Tutorial isCookieSet={isCookieSet} setIsCookieSet={setIsCookieSet} cookies={cookies} setCookie={setCookie} removeCookie={removeCookie} handleClose={handleClose} show={show} ></Tutorial>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements do not load. `onload` event(s) can only be used in several elements of the DOM, and `div` is not one of them. `onload` events can only be used with these: `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<style>`.

The solution to your problem is to use a hook, in this case we use `useEffect`. Here's a fixed version of your code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

function App() {
  const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(["janganTampil"]);
  const [isCookieSet, setIsCookieSet] = useState(false);
  // state for modal
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  function checkCookie() {
    const tampil = cookies.janganTampil === 'true';
    if (tampil) {
      setIsCookieSet(true);
    } else {
      handleShow();
    }
    console.log(isCookieSet);
    console.log(show);
  }

  // An effect which will be loaded once on load. `[]` means
  // no dependencies, so the hook will only be run just once only.
  useEffect(() => {
    // Call this function when this hook is running. It isn't
    // and async function or the like, so a 'normal call' like this
    // is enough.
    checkCookie();
  }, []);

  // Notice that I deleted the `onLoaded` prop here. It isn't valid.
  return (
    <div className="App">
      ...
      {/* Tutorial is modal */}
      <Tutorial isCookieSet={isCookieSet} setIsCookieSet={setIsCookieSet} cookies={cookies} setCookie={setCookie} removeCookie={removeCookie} handleClose={handleClose} show={show} ></Tutorial>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

References:

- [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)
- [`onLoad`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: can I delete the `onLoaded`? @Nicholas

Comment: Of course you can delete it. `onLoaded` is not a valid prop anyways, so deleting it would cause no problems at all. I've edited my answer to also delete that prop.